# RESTHeart Bind Error to MongoDB on AmazonAWS

Tags: mongodb, rest, bind, restheart

I am trying to assist a customer in getting RESTHeart up and connected to MongoDB that is hosted on AmazonAWS. The startup from the yml file looks like it is connecting to our MongoDB (yellow highlight in attachment) but then it fails with a bind error.  Have tried setting the mongo-uri with and without port, IP and hostname all with the same result.  I checked the softinstigate site for help or a forum and they suggest here.  Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[Statup log with DEBUG on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahFTi.png)

Answer (score 1):

The http and https are bound to the same address. This is not possible.

In the log I also spot 
     Mongodb version: ?

This is usually due to restheart not communicating with mongodb. You have to check your network settings...

Are you able to telnet to mongodb from the host running restheart?

Comment: Additionally, it seems it's binding RESTHeart to port 27017, which is usually the Mongodb one... It looks like there is some confusion there :)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Going to try again and report back.